VLC in python tkinter script, Raspberry PI, video playback stutters
I have developed a kiosk system that runs on a Raspberry Pi 4B. It runs Raspberry Pi OS Lite (bookworm) and openbox as window manager. The content (text, images and videos) is displayed by a Python script with Tkinter. I set up the whole system in January/February 2024. Everything runs cleanly, on various TVs up to 4K resolution, even videos (e.g. MP4 H264 FullHD) smoothly.
def play_video(item):
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(vid_path + item['video'])
    player.set_media(media)
    player.toggle_fullscreen()
    player.play()
    time.sleep(1)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)
    player.stop()


The device is due to go into production soon. To avoid starting with an outdated system, I recently carried out an update (apt update and upgrade). After that, the same videos only run very poorly and jerkily. It's probably not the Python script, that hasn't been changed. One of the many updates must have changed something. A test system without updates, from the beginning of the year, is still running fine.
One of the updates must have changed something. I suspect the Raspi itself (firmware, eeprom, settings), maybe also VLC.
I'm just not able to figure out where to look for and fix this problem.

Can you give us a full [mre]? Also if you are using tkinter, you should be careful with using time.sleep as tkinter can't update the screen while it's sleeping.
